# High Resolution RDP on 30" portrait monitors showing with black line at the top and bottom

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, remote

Can anyone tell me how to get 30" monitors to work in portrait mode with RDP in high resolution?  I'm having an issue whereby I remote desktop into Windows Server 2008 R2 from Windows 7 x64.  Our screens are 30" in portrait and when used with mstsc /SPAN mode we can stretch it over two 30" screens but the height is tapered by a black line at the top and bottom.  I believe this is due to remote desktop having a maximum height resolution of 2048.

Any help would be great as I'm stuck on this one!